# Should moderators be able to add to the weekly newsletter?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, moderators

Right now, most of the newsletters that I've seen are pretty plain.

Should a moderator be given the power to add a few notes to the newsletter, such as motivations for the community, or just a message they would like to get out there?

Comment: Seems like using the [featured] tag on Meta has always worked just fine for this - what advantage would be gain by putting something in the newsletter?

Comment: @Undo Thanks for clearing that up; I've sort-of always wondered how that [tag:featured] thing worked. I thought that adding something to the newsletter would just change things up a bit from the usual "hot posts" that you see.

Comment: Having featured meta posts find their way into the newsletters would be handy.  One of the things I use newsletter subscriptions for is to keep an eye on sites I'm *kind of* interested in but don't visit regularly.  So I never see the community bulletin there, but I would see something in a newsletter.